# Is it possible to access to a class instance that it is inside another class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to access an object instantiated inside a class, but something isn't working.

I have three classes: App, Map, Player

App class instantiated map class

```js
class App {
 constructor(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase) {
   this.map = new Map(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase);
 }
}
```

Map

Inside `Map` class, is instantiated the `Player` class. My main problem, is that I can´t access the instance of `Player` to access to its methods

```js
class Map {
 constructor(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase) {
  this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  this.canvas.width = sizeX * sizeCase;
  this.canvas.height = sizeY * sizeCase;
  this.size = { x: sizeX, y: sizeY, case: sizeCase };
 }
 setPlayers(quantity) {
  for (let index = 0; index < quantity; index++) {
   let x = App.random(this.size.x);
   let y = App.random(this.size.y);
   if (this.mapGame[x][y] == 0) {
    switch (index) {
     case 0:
      let player1 = new Player("vampi", 100, y, x);
      break;
      case 1:
       let player2 = new Player("wolfi", 100, y, x);
       break;
       default:
       break;
    }
  }else {
    console.log("Position occupied");
    index--;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Player

```js
class Player {
 constructor(name, score, positionY, positionX) {
  this.name = name;
  this.score = score;
 }
 drawPlayer(playerImage) {
  app.map.mapGame[this.y][this.x] = 2;
 }
}
```

Most of the questions I have read here are related to java, and the javascript ones I have found, are not related to my question, or I didn´t find the relation after reading them.

The console says:

> "TypeError: app.map.player1 is undefined"

Comment: JavaScript already has a `Map` class, you shouldn't use that name for your own class.

Comment: The `Player` constructor never sets `this.x` and `this.y`.

Comment: `setPlayers` never does anything with `player1` and `player2`. What is the purpose of those variables?

Comment: @Barmar I will change the Map class. thanks. I deleted this.x and this.y
setPlayers create two objects player1 and player2 I didn´t want to put the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not the same as class properties. To make `app.map.player1` work, you need to assign the property.

```
setPlayers(quantity) {
  for (let index = 0; index < quantity; index++) {
    let x = App.random(this.size.x);
    let y = App.random(this.size.y);
    if (this.mapGame[x][y] == 0) {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          this.player1 = new Player("vampi", 100, y, x);
          break;
        case 1:
          this.player2 = new Player("wolfi", 100, y, x);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Position occupied");
      index--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the players on the map, and the class player has a method to move them. If I instantiate the class from app, I can access to player1 just typing app.player1 
I alredy did, but I don´t like that way so, I was trying to set the players from map class

Comment: Isn't that what this does?

Comment: I don´t follow you, sorry.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your previous comment. `player1` isn't set in the `App` class, it's only set in the `Map` class.